# Tesla model 3 motor

Tags: electric-machine

The Tesla's model 3 uses IPM-SRM motor in the rear drive. 
This motor is fed by AC supply OR DC supply? 
Is the motor's stator is of salient pole construction OR the same stator as of the induction motor?
I have read that this motor is a three phase, 6 pole configuration. How exactly is it's stator's construction? Three salient poles with shared poles OR 6 poles making three phases.[image]

Comment: Are those bars through the rotor permanent magnets? If yes, it's a synchronous machine. Do they run through the whole rotor, or just the tips? If the latter, the centre of the rotor is an additional asynchronous machine. Both may be fed by the same AC coil on the stator. This isn't a salient pole construction.

Comment: A Tesla principal power electronics engineer explains their choice of using induction motors instead of the more-common DC brushless:  https://www.tesla.com/blog/induction-versus-dc-brushless-motors

Comment: @calcium3000: The linked explanation is about the original Tesla motor. This one is clearly a permanent-magnet synchronous motor.

Comment: @Janka: An asynchronous machine can not produce torque at synchronous speed. Therefore the center section must be something else.

Comment: @Charles Cowie: That additional asychronous machine would be only meant for starting. It's simpler to build an inverter and machine that goes down to e.g. 20Hz than one that goes down to DC.

Comment: @Janka: Industrial VFDs have been starting motors from 1 or 2 Hz for 50 years. It would be difficult to start an induction motor at 20 Hz. I view the idea that Tesla has an induction motor built in as extremely unlikely. That would also mean a substantial part of the motor volume and weight not contributing to regular operation. That is completely contrary to the reports that this motor delivers 40% better performance vs. size compared to competitors.

Answer (score 2):

> This motor is fed by AC supply OR DC supply?

It is supplied and controlled by an inverter that converts DC from the battery to AC to supply the three-phase AC IPMSM.

> Is the motor's stator is of salient pole construction OR the same stator as of the induction motor? I have read that this motor is a three phase, 6 pole configuration. How exactly is it's stator's construction? Three salient poles with shared poles OR 6 poles making three phases.

The stator construction would be identical to the construction of a 6-pole induction motor stator. The 6 stator poles are formed by distributed windings with windings of three phases making up each phase.